# Display alert dialog while running an Android test case

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, robotium

I am using Robotium to automate testing of an application. Is there a way I can display an alert box while executing a particular test case.

Thanks.

Comment: I tried using toast but it dint work :(

Comment: This is what I did                        Toast.makeText(solo.getCurrentActivity(), "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: what it does? This doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do, nearly everything is possible but before I give you the answer do you have a good reason to do this? I cant easily thing of a good reason why a test should open an alert box but you may know best.

Robotium has the method.

```
solo.getCurrentActivity();
```

Using this you can get an Activity Context and with such a thing you can do pretty much anything that you could do in an android activity. The page http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html tells us how to make a dialog, you will notice the first line calls a method to get the currentActivity, instead of that I replaced it with the robotium method above.

```
// 1. Instantiate an AlertDialog.Builder with its constructor
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(solo.getCurrentActivity());

// 2. Chain together various setter methods to set the dialog characteristics
builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message)
       .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);

// 3. Get the AlertDialog from create()
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
```

this will create a dialog, then just call the dialogs .show() method to show it on the screen.

Comment: First of all thanks :). Paul I wanted to do this because the test process requires a manual process. So to perform this manual process, the idea was to halt the execution of automated test until the manual process completes and then the user can press the ok button of the dialogue to continue the test process. I tried the code given above, there are no error but it is not showing the alert . :(

Comment: I had also tried this AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(getInstrumentation().getContext()).create();  
  ad.setCancelable(false); // This blocks the 'BACK' button  
  ad.setMessage("Hello World");  
  ad.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
      @Override  
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
      {  
          dialog.dismiss();                      
      }  
  });  
  ad.show();

Comment: You will as noted in the other answer need to run it on the main thread to get it to show. The bigger issue is im not sure you will get the functionality you want. What is the manual process you need to do? the problem with an alert is that you will not be able to do anything in your application while it is visible.

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to do. Don't do anything until alert is visible. As long as alert is visible, user can press on button of a remote control and the test app can check if the TV is on.  This was just for an example.

Comment: I would look at trying to stub out anything that requires that sort of functionality from your automated tests, having manual steps like this make them slow and annoying when you can 99% of the time check your code is calling the correct methods and then 1% of the time just manually check the real implementation is doing the expected thing.

Answer (score 0):

Robotium tests do not run on the UI Thread, so any code in a test method will in the best case just not work and in the worst case throw and error and cause your test to fail.

To interact with the UI from inside a test method you need to run your code on the UI Thread. This can be done by writing that code inside a Runnable, and sending that Runnable to the `runOnUiThread()` method of the current Activity.  Robotium's solo class has the `getCurrentActivity()` method, which will allow this execution.  Here's an example of how you'd show a Toast using this technique.

```
public void testDisplayToastInActivity() throws Exception
{
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            Toast.makeText(solo.getCurrentActivity(), "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    solo.getCurrentActivity().runOnUiThread(runnable);
 }
```

You can use `runOnUiThread()` to perform many other actions that interact with your Activity, such as creating Alert Dialogs, if you want something more than a Toast.  However, I'd suggest against doing any of this, even though you can.  Robotium and other testing frameworks are meant to judge the correctness of your application code's execution, and should not inject any logic or UI modifying behavior beyond interacting with your application the way a user would.  Your tests will be cleaner if you take any outpu from your tests and log them to Logcat or a file.